# How to manage article/chronoform permissions

Tags: joomla-3.x, permissions, chronoforms

How to create one article which is when user who log in will see chronoform form and they can insert information; but when visitor who does not log in to the website only can view the information which is inserted by the user ( the data inserted by the user will be saved in the database and will be displayed to the visitor)

let's say i write {chronoforms}Form_Title{/chronoforms} in the article editor to create the form. Where am i suppose to put a code to display the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used CromoForms however this is possible with [RSForms](https://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/rsform.html) (free).

Using RSForms you would create your form, and as you know all the data is saved in the database. However you can also display this data on the front-end using a special '**Submissions**' menu item.

The Submissions menu item permits you to display the submissions in the front-end for a form of your choice. The menu item can be added to your site from the Menu Manager section in the back-end, to any menu on your site. You can then set the permissions for this menu item to be **non-registered** users (or whoever you choose). This way non-registered users will not be able to fill in the form, but they will be able to see the form results.

Like I say this method is for RSForms which is free, however someting similar may be possible using ChromoForms.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In ChronoForms v5, edit your form, go to the Setup tab and drag an "Authenticator" action into the appropriate event in your form:

[image: ChronoForms Authenticator Action]

Edit the Authenticator properties to set the required permissions:

[image: ChronoForms Authenticator Properties]

You can then drag appropriate actions into "On Success" or "On Fail" as appropriate.

For example, you might drag a "Display Message" action into the "On Fail" and set the message to, "Please log in as Administrator to complete this action" or similar.

ChronoForms v4 has similar functionality.

Comment: I couldn't find the 'Authenticator' in Easy Wizard Form